# How to scroll through a count query in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
select count(*) , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 34.469994 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( -118.196739 ) ) + sin( radians( 34.469994 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance from users HAVING distance < 150
```

Which is supposed to get users within 150 miles of a certain latitude and longitude.
How can I get the number of the count(*) part?

Also, any idea how to toggle such a query between miles and kilometers?

Thanks!

Comment: count(*) AS count for the count part

Comment: You may want to take a look at MySQL's support for spatial data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(*) as count, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 34.469994 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( -118.196739 ) ) + sin( radians( 34.469994 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance from users HAVING distance < 150
```